this code show an reshape error. how fix this?
I'm new in python and ML. I wrote this code for practicing. It displays this error. how do I solve this reshape problem?
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as skl

data=pd.read_csv('housing.csv')
housing=data['ocean_proximity']
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
encoder=OneHotEncoder()
housing_cat_fac=housing.factorize()
housing_final=encoder.fit_transform(housing_cat_fac.reshape(1,-1))

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-b13a23adc636> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 encoder=OneHotEncoder()
      8 housing_cat_fac=housing.factorize()
----> 9 housing_final=encoder.fit_transform(housing_cat_fac.reshape(1,-1))

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'reshape'


In general if x.y gives an attribute error, either you read the docs for x class objects wrong, or (more likely) xisn't the class you expected.  Withreshapeyou probably expectedx` to be an array, not a tuple.  Either way you need to reread the relevant docs.

factorize returns a tuple of the factorized values and unique original values.
Thus housing_cat_fac=housing.factorize() will make housing_cat_fac a tuple.
You should use:
housing_cat_fac = housing.factorize()[0]

Or, if you want to keep the original values:
housing_cat_fac, uniq_vals = housing.factorize()

Then housing_cat_fac will be a numpy array.
